# sql pivot function for a table with only 2 columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I'm trying to use the pivot function in SQL Server to transform some results, but I'm running into trouble.

The table only has 2 columns, which look like this:

```
company      category
-----        -----
company 1    Arcade 
company 1    Action 
company 2    Arcade 
company 2    Adventure
```

I'd like to transform it to this:

```
company      category 1     category 2
-----        -----          -----
company 1    Arcade         Action    
company 2    Arcade         Adventure
```

So far all I can find are examples of pivot functions where there is a 3rd column in the original results with "category 1" or "category 2", which then uses the values in those column as the names of the new, pivoted columns.

What I want to do is simply define the names of the columns from scratch. Is there a way to do this with the pivot function?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need a third column that contains `category1`, `category2`, etc, then I would suggest applying a windowing function like [`row_number()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to your data first before attempting to convert the data into columns.  The `row_number()` function will create a unique sequenced number for each `company` and `category`, you will then use this calculated value to pivot the data.

The easiest way to convert the data would be to use an aggregate function along with a CASE expression.  First, you will use a subquery to generate the `row_number()`:

```
select company,
  max(case when seq = 1 then category end) Category1,
  max(case when seq = 2 then category end) Category2
from
(
  select company, category,
    row_number() over(partition by company
                              order by company) seq
  from yourtable
) d
group by company;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5416/3).

Now, if you want to use the PIVOT function you would still use the `row_number()`, but you would place the new calculated sequence as the new column names:

```
select company, category1, category2
from
(
  select company, category,
    'category'+
      cast(row_number() over(partition by company
                              order by company) as varchar(10)) seq
  from yourtable
) d
pivot
(
  max(category)
  for seq in (Category1, Category2)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5416/4). These generate a result of:

```
|   COMPANY | CATEGORY1 | CATEGORY2 |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| company 1 |    Arcade |    Action |
| company 2 |    Arcade | Adventure |
```