# SQL, Merge data into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query to get a specific `Area`:

```
Select 
    Id, Name 
from 
    Area 
Where 
    (Id = 1)
```

Each `Area` can have 2 files in `AreaFiles` table, so I changed the query to:

```
SELECT     
    Area.Id, Area.Name, AreaFiles.FileName
FROM
    AreaFiles 
INNER JOIN
    Area ON AreaFiles.AreaId = Area.Id
WHERE
    (Area.Id = 1)
```

The result is:

```
Id | Name | FileName
--- ------ ----------
1    abc     file1.jpg
1    abc     file2.jpg
```

I want to merge these rows into one row to get this:

```
Id | Name | FileName1 | FileName2
--- ------ ------------------------
1    abc     file1.jpg   file1.jpg
```

Is it possible?

Comment: What you are trying is pivoting table. Take a look here at SO, there are countless answers.

Comment: @Eyal [see this post for an example of how you'd do this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21972199/sql-pivot-function-for-a-table-with-only-2-columns)

Answer (score 4):

To achieve this, you will need to use `PIVOT`

See here for a good example - http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query

So for your eample here, it would be

```
SELECT ID,NAME, [1] AS FILENAME1, [2] AS FILENAME2 FROM
(SELECT ID, FILENAME, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS ROWNUM) FROM AREA A
PIVOT ((MAX(ID) FOR ROWNUM IN [1],[2])) AS PVT
```

Comment: Added an example to my answer

Answer (score -1):

for that you need to use with clause

```
with first as (select id,name,filename from area),
     second as (select id,name,filename from area)

SELECT first.id,first.name,first.filename,second.filename
FROM first,second
where first.id=second.id;
```

Comment: try to improve it .. it required little more efforts to be right