# Pivot only one row with two column using SQL

Tags: sql-server

We have one row with two column and we want to Pivot it any help plz.

Ex:

---

### |   A    |    B    |

and the required out put is

---

### |    A     |

### |    B     |

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of below:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21972199/sql-pivot-function-for-a-table-with-only-2-columns

Comment: Sir We have Only one Row and Two Columns not more than that.

Comment: Kindly share your work so far. If there is any code, script or approach you made.